# css3 slide up transistion

Tags: html, css, show-hide

Hi I've got a Div I wont to expose on Click of a link, it reveals a pop up at the bottom of the page... at the moment it looks like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/XPJC5/

```
body{margin:0;}
#lightbox {
        display:none;
        position:absolute;
        bottom:5px;
        z-index:1000;
        width:100%;
        background-color:#09F;
        height:50px;
        float:left;
        font-family: 'helvetica_bqregular';
        font-size:20px;
        line-height:65px;
        color:#FFF;
        text-align:center;
            }

 /* works with IE8+, Firefox 2+, Safari, Chrome, Opera 10+ */

 #lightbox:target {
         display:block;
      }

<a href="#lightbox" style="color:#999; text-decoration:underline;">Register</a>
<div id="lightbox">

          <div style=" background-color:#CBE376; width:100%; line-height:65px; height:65px; border-bottom:solid #999 thin; -webkit-box-shadow:  4px 4px 4px 4px #333;box-shadow:  4px 4px 4px 4px #333; clear:both;">
Consumer
          </div>
          <div style=" background-color:#94C8F1; line-height:65px; width:100%; height:65px;">

             Business</div>
    <div style=" background-color:#333; width:100%; height:65px;"><a href="#" style="color:#fff; text-decoration:none;">Close</a>

          </div></div>
```

but I want the box to slide up from the bottom similar to this:
http://jsfiddle.net/R8zca/4/

Can anyone help with accomplishment? seems to fail on trial.

Thanks

Comment: Is the CSS separate from the HTML?

Comment: Well, if you won't use the CSS `transition` properties as in the original, then obviously it won't work... If you *have* tried, show us what you did and explain how it failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the heights from the inline styles in the html and set the boxes to an initial height of 0px in the css, then use the css transition to bring them to full height

html

```
<a href="#lightbox" style="color:#999; text-decoration:underline;">Register</a>
<div id="lightbox">

          <div style=" background-color:#CBE376; width:100%; line-height:65px; border-bottom:solid #999 thin; -webkit-box-shadow:  4px 4px 4px 4px #333;box-shadow:  4px 4px 4px 4px #333; clear:both;">
Consumer
          </div>
          <div style=" background-color:#94C8F1; line-height:65px; width:100%; ">

             Business</div>
    <div style=" background-color:#333; width:100%;"><a href="#" style="color:#fff; text-decoration:none;">Close</a>

          </div></div>
```

css

```
body{margin:0;}
#lightbox div
{
    height: 0px;
}
#lightbox {
        display:block;
        position:absolute;
        bottom:5px;
        z-index:1000;
        width:100%;
        background-color:#09F;
        float:left;
        font-family: 'helvetica_bqregular';
        font-size:20px;
        line-height:65px;
        color:#FFF;
        text-align:center;
            }

 /* works with IE8+, Firefox 2+, Safari, Chrome, Opera 10+ */

#lightbox:target div
{
    height: 65px;
    -webkit-transition:all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition:all 1s ease;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/axrwkr/XPJC5/2

Comment: Close I want it to slide up though as an entire box, also I cant seem to get the bottom grey div with the shadow to disappear

Comment: Managed it thanks I went along your lines, will upload it to jsfiddle in a bit to show what I did :) Thank You once again